# Ways to provide Metadata to Classes, Properties etc

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, metadata

I am thinking about ways for providing metadata / metainfo for classes and properties in C#.

So far the only thing I have come across are Attributes, which are nice to provide metainfos, however they are only accessible via an instance of the class/property that "contains" them.

is there any way to provide static metadata?

Reflection for accessing the Property or Class names is too possible, but again like attributes only possible if you have an instance, and additional you might need a string.

An approach to provide static Metainfo for classes could be to create a static property and use it for this purpose.
Like this:

```
Class A
{
    public static string Name { get{return "ClassA";}}
}
```

However for properties this is not possible.

My specific problem is that i have multiple classes each having a "second" name (needed for certain Serialization purposes). The Class Name itself and another one. This can be done via providing a static property like said before.

However each of these classes has properties that should have 2 names too.

Up to know i provide this by having a custom attribute for each property, but that is only a workaround, since i might need that second name without having an instance of the class.
Only solution if i use attributes is creating an instance and accessing the attributes in that way (in the case that the properties are not null after class instantiation, otherwise they need to be instantiated too...)

```
Class A
{
    [customAttribute("secondName")]
    public string property{ get; set;}
}
```

I would love to hear about some general approaches for providing metainfo in c#, and of course if someone has an idea for my problem too ;)

**Edit:** If the Metainfo is accessible during Compiletime, not Runtime, this would be ideal.

Comment: What do you mean by `however they are only accessible via an instance of the class/property that "contains" them`? Attributes doesn't need instances, You just need to know the type of the class to find its attributes.

Comment: Try accessing the attribute of the property in my second example without an instance of Class A, thats what i mean^^

Comment: @Visions the only instance you need for that is `Type aType = typeof (A);`

Comment: You can access it without an instance like this `string secondName = typeof (A).GetProperty("property").GetCustomAttribute<customAttribute>().Name;`

Comment: hm true, but IMHO that would not be much better than writing the second name in code again. If the name of the property changes i would need to change every "property" string used by this approach

Comment: then write code that uses reflection and write an anonymous method to select it. Then you get compile time checking. Look at implementations of propertyChanged event handlers for lots of examples.